# Array with object index not getting as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
let arr = []
```

I am inserting an object into it

```
let a = {name:"a", age: 20}
arr.push(a);
```

I am checking index with below with same object assigned to different variable

```
let b = {name:"a", age:20}
```

I tried

```
arr.indexOf(b);
```

I am getting -1 I expect 0.

Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS does object comparison (and search) by reference, not by value. Hence: for `foo == bar` to be true, foo and bar must be the same object, not just an object with the same properties and values:

```js
console.log({name:"a", age:20} == {name:"a", age:20});
```

Hence instead of indexOf, you need something like findIndex.

```js
let arr = [];
let a = {name:"a", age: 20};
arr.push(a);
let b = {name:"a", age:20}

const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.name === b.name && item.age === b.age);
console.log(index);
```

Comment: indexOf uses `===` not `==` mate

Comment: The principle is true for both == and ===.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, objects are reference type, the variable `a` and `b` points to two different memory locations. Thus  `a != b`

```js
let a = {name:"a", age: 20};
let b = {name:"a", age:20}
console.log(a == b);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can not compare objects by default. Use `Array.findIndex` instead:

```js
let arr = []

let a = {name:"a", age: 20}

arr.push(a);
let b = {name:"a", age:20}


console.log(arr.findIndex(elem => elem.name == b.name && elem.age == b.age));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because Js compare by using reference not by value

```js
let arr = [];

let a = {
  name: "a",
  age: 20
};
arr.push(a);

let b = {
  name: "a",
  age: 20
};

console.log(arr.indexOf(b));
```

```js
let arr = [];

let a = {
  name: "a",
  age: 20
};
arr.push(a);

let b = a

console.log(arr.indexOf(b));
```